# How to control blocking sessions while an index maintenance job runs?

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, index-maintenance

I would like to know, is there any possibility to control the locks while Ola's index optimize job is running?

I have implemented Ola Hallengren's index optimize job and am running it every day, but it is blocking the user transactions and causing performance issues.

How can I avoid blocking and locks while an index job is running?

Comment: Which version / edition of SQL server are you using?

Comment: There is an important consideration based on whether or not you are doing a REBUILD. Currently, only the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server can perform a REBUILD without locking the index for the entire index for the entire rebuild time by using the ONLINE option. If this is a problem, you probably have to use REORGANIZE instead, unless you can bring your system down during the rebuilds.

Comment: If you have a window of opportunity (i.e. off-business hours during the week, weekends, etc.) then I would schedule the index optimize job during that window. However, I'd be asking myself if I really needed to run those index jobs every night: [link](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/index-maintenance-madness/)

Answer (score 1):

Not really controlling solution but you may try new index rebuild options :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

::=
{
    WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY ( MAX_DURATION =  [ MINUTES ] ,
                          ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = { NONE | SELF | BLOCKERS } )
}

this way you may control behavior of maintenance operation if it is blocking other processes.